# Windows Virtual Desktop behind the VPN

Tags: wvd

> is it possible to have Windows Virtual Desktop behind the vpn, currently it working fine as wvd service**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

WVD Uses Azure AD for authentication which is fully could service, but if you are interested in adding more security layers to your Windows Virtual Desktop Env, you can benefit of Conditional Access adding polices that requires multi-factor authentication and many other conditions like ( User Location, Client App, Device Platform) when connecting to Windows Virtual Desktop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/set-up-mfa#create-a-conditional-access-policy

Comment: Yes i did that and set up one condition access policy to allow users with some specific set of ip range , but every time i have to enter ip , so want to restrict users only use WVD when they connected to vpn

Comment: In such case, you can just restrict access to a conditional access policy with a named location using your VPN network Public IP.

Comment: I tried with VPN Public IP but it does not work and it only works when i mention the public ip address range which shows to the client on whatismyip.com site as they work from home and WVD URL bound with their Dynamic IP receive from their internet provider